# Good practices when installing from sources on Linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, compiling, make, source

I'm wondering what are good practices about compilation and manual installation of software on Linux systems.
I mean getting, building and installing code by this usual way :

```
git clone https://a-repo/foo.git
cd foo/
./configure
make
make install
```

- Should that be avoided ? Or is it recommended ?
  Maybe it is better to make a package for the distribution in use ?
- Are there some tricks to manage versions and updates ?
- Does good practices exists when doing `./configure`, particularly
  with `--prefix=` ?
- How can I install / uninstall properly ? Should I always keep the
  sources to do `make uninstall` ?
- I have seen some tools like `stow`, but this seems to be a
  controversial solution... Maybe an other one ?

I prefer solutions that are independents of distro, but all suggestions and advices are welcome !
Thank you !

**EDIT:** It seems that people don't understand my question. I'm not opening a debate, I just want an answer as clear as possible for the various points above. I really think this could be helpful for some people. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: TLDR Use `--prefix=/opt/something` or even `--prefix=/opt/something-VERSION`. No issues with deinstalling, installing, keeping track of versions, etc. Don't wanna write an answer - there's just too much to talk about.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I know there is a lot to say about, I would just like to have an overview and different opinions on this topic ;-)

Comment: This question isn't really suitable for a stackexchange site: the answers are going to be a matter of discussion and opinion. There are probably some reddits that would be a good fit. But as long as I'm here, I really like [stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) for managing source-installed software.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I didn't think about Reddit. I'm looking for a kind of checklist, so I tought that SE was good for that... I'll try a bit more `stow`, I like the concept of this minimalistic software. The problems I encountered with `stow` were about some symlinks not working, mainly for `systemd` services.

Comment: Three words:  document, Document, **DOCUMENT**.  When I was a telephone support tech for a company with Unix/Linux products, I spoke with many, many engineers who joined a company and had to puzzle out the software and configs left behind by a previous engineer.  Among those were programs installed from source rather than from the package manager.  Write down in a wiki or Google Docs the general steps you use to build your programs and where you install them.  The engineer you help with this will even be you -- in a year when you need to update things and can't remember the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your method is figuring out what files have to be deleted when you want to uninstall the software.

The best practice is to build a package for the distribution.  This has several advantages.  It allows you to easily install, upgrade, & remove packages.  It allows you to compile the software on a seperate machine avoiding putting compilers on every machine.  It allows you to easily upgrade the package when the upstream goes to another version/release.  And, it allows you to build the software without being root.

A quick & dirty work around I used before I learned how to use rpmbuild & spec files was to:

```
./configure
make
make DESTDIR=/tmp/build install
```

This puts all the "installed" files with the correct installation tree under the /tmp/build directory.  Then change the owner/group for all the files in the directory.  Then:

`tar cvfj <filename> -C /tmp/build/`

To install them:
`tar xvf <filename> -C /`
To uninstall them:
`tar tf <filename> | xargs rm`

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I think this is something like that I want ! I tried this 
```bash
tar cvjf ed.tar.bz2 -C /tmp/build/
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.` But I got this error as you can see.
```
So tried `tar cvjf ed.tar.bz2 -C /tmp/build/ .`, but this creates a problem when uninstalling:  
```bash
rm: impossible de supprimer './usr/local/': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Comment: I did this but it is a little dirty ;-) `tar tf ed.tar.bz2 | sed -e 's/^.//' | xargs rm`

Comment: @thiblcr Whatever works.  However, if you are going to be doing a lot of these, you should take the time to learn how to build packages.  Another resource is "pkgs.org".  Someone may have already built the package for your distro.

Comment: Yeah thank you very much, your solution is very simple, I 'll keep this trick... I'm mainly on Gentoo, so I'll need to learn how to write ebuilds. I think you're right about building packages, this seems to be the better way !